# Is there a way to log all the resources used by an application?

Tags: windows-7, logging

I'd like to find out what the bottleneck is for various applications/games. So to do that it would be nice if there was some application that would record all the resources used by another application, like how many cores does it use, does it take full advantage of the GPU, was the RAM access fast enough, was the HDD access fast enough?

I know Windows comes with Resource Monitor, but it doesn't seem to have what I need. Can anyone recommend and application (runnable on Win 7) that would help me identify bottlenecks?

Comment: when an application acts sluggish, I do ctrl-alt-delete and see it is eating a lot of ram(sluggish probably because virtual memory gets used if available ram is low). i've never needed to look for another cause.. but I know another can be using a lot of cpu.. also shown by ctrl-alt-delete. when a computer acts sluggish I close processes or applications that I think are the culprit, and the problem goes eventually, and the culprit tends to be found from that.

Comment: As much as I appreciate tips, barlop, modern applications and especially games depend on more than just the CPU, hence the reason for this question...

Comment: Apparently Riva Tuner is good, it's for an NVIDIA based GPU. There is something called Rightmark memory analyzer, may be worth a try for RAM. There is ntune probably for nvidia based only (chipset I suppose) only, ntune is mentione here one guy doesn't like it though http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=56008.   And you could look generally at game developer tools, used to analyse their performance. That thread mentions 2.

Answer (score 2):

The tools from sysinternals can be used for this...they may be a little complicated or non-intuitive for some users.  They are available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

Comment: It's a start...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at your [Windows-Experience-Index](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-the-Windows-Experience-Index)?

It's probably easier than profiling each game!

Comment: Yes, I have. I find it completely useless.